# Change data encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I get some data from the server in Unicode. However I need this data in UTF8. How can I convert data to UTF8 encoding?

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding. Unicode is a set of encoding standards. UTF8 is an encoding. UTF8 is an implementation of Unicode.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What do you mean by "convert"?  Do you mean you got character data in UTF-16 or Latin-1 and you need to *re-encode* it in UTF-8?

Comment: yes, I got data in Unicode and I actually need to get data in NSCStringEncoding as a result. I can achieve this by using extra string, but I am looking for more easy method.

Comment: @Olga Dalton: There's no such thing as “NSCStringEncoding”. The `cStringEncoding` is a deprecated concept; C-strings should be either in an explicit encoding or created using the `fileSystemRepresentation` method (when you intend to use them with the file system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution is that that the server sends you UTF-8 in the first place.

UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode, so depending on what you mean by “Unicode” in your question, it may already be doing that.

Cocoa misuses “Unicode” in the symbol `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` to refer to UTF-16. It's possible, but unlikely, that that's what the server is sending you.

The server should tell you in the Content-Type header what encoding it used for the content. You should look at that in your program rather than assuming the server will use any specific encoding.

If the encoding is not specified in the header, try treating it as UTF-8, and if that doesn't work, I suggest complaining to whoever runs the server.

To convert from any encoding supported by Cocoa to UTF-8, pass the input data and the encoding it's in to [the `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData%3aencoding%3a), which will decode the data and produce a string; then, send the string [a `dataUsingEncoding:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/dataUsingEncoding%3a) with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` as the desired encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Well UTF-8 *is* an encoding for Unicode, but to get a string:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: That only works if the data was encoded in UTF-8 to begin with. It doesn't convert anything *to* UTF-8.